# Modular exponentiation references

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I have [recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580774/modulus-trick-in-programming) [learned](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/554427/86846) a trick in modular exponentiation that is new to me.  By example (as in the linked question/answer above):

$$2^{1386}=2^{2^{10}}\cdot 2^{2^8}\cdot 2^{2^6}\cdot 2^{2^5}\cdot 2^{2^3}\cdot 2^{2^1}\equiv 2^{2^6}\cdot 2^{2^5}\cdot 2^{2^4}\cdot 2^{2^3}\cdot 2^{2^2}\cdot 2^{2^1}\pmod {1387}$$

since it was found that $2^{2^7}\equiv 2^{2^1}\pmod {1387}.$

After a little thought, I stumbled upon the notion that changing the exponentiation base from $2$ to $3$ might yield a similar result, and in fact I found that

$$1386_{10}=10101101010_2=1220100_3$$

Nothing spectacular about this, except when computing $2^{1386}\pmod{1387}$ using a cubing operation instead of squaring:

$$2^3=8\\
8^3=512\\
512^3\equiv 512\pmod{1387}$$

So we have that $2^{3^3}\equiv 2^{3^2}\pmod{1387}$, which means that

$$2^{3^6+2\cdot 3^5+2\cdot 3^4+3^2}\equiv 2^{6\cdot 3^2}\equiv 2^{2\cdot 3^3}\equiv 2^{2\cdot 3^2}\equiv 512^2\equiv 1\pmod{1387}$$

This seems to be a very useful result.  Using repeated squaring, it took $7$ steps to identify a repeat point like this.

Are there any good references on this particular feature of modular exponentiation?  In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666269/is-it-possible-to-solve-i2i1-equiv-0-pmod2p-1-in-general) I was attempting to apply the above logic to Mersenne Primes (without success).

One obvious difficulty with this process is that there is no guarantee that a given base will produce effective results; this was especially true in my trials with Mersenne Primes, where finding an exponent that would produce a "small" repeat proved very difficult.  So I would like to get information on the theory surrounding this topic to perhaps improve my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bit information regarding *basic theory* and certain *applications of modular exponentiation*.

> *Basics: Elementary Number Theory*

As far as I know *modular exponentiation* is, embedded within modular arithmetic, a relatively small part of *elementary number theory*. So, you will presumably not find complete books dealing with this theme. The basic information can be found by looking through some of the books about *elementary number theory*. See e.g. chapter $4$ of [Elementary Number Theory with Applications](http://worldtracker.org/media/library/Mathematics/Algebra%20&%20Trigonometry/Koshy%20-%20Elementary%20Number%20Theory%20with%20Applications%202e%20%28Elsevier,%202007%29.pdf) from *Thomas Koshy* with a small section about *Modular Exponentiation* (and a comment, which may surprise you).

Here's a nice online summary about [Modular Arithmetic](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/crypto/modular_arithmetic_intro.htm) with a special section about [Modular Exponentiation](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/crypto/modular_exponentiation.htm).

> *Applications: Finite Fields and Cryptography*

Much less elementary are *applications using modular exponentiation*. They can be found in *finite fields* and *cryptography*, whereby finding fast algorithms is the main stimulus. Here  are two papers just to give you a first impression. These papers are not necessarily representative for the current development, since I'm not an expert (only sometimes a practitioner using certain cryptographic techniques).

*Finite Fields*:
In [Algorithms for Exponentiation in Finite Fields](http://www.math.clemson.edu/~sgao/papers/GGPS00.pdf) you will see how fast exponentiation in finite fields $\mathbb{F}_q^n$ is presented with $q$ a small prime power (not only base $2$) and polynomial basis exponentiation in $\mathbb{F}_2^n$.

*Cryptography*:
The other paper which could be of interest for you shows how *modular exponentiation* is employed for creating a *fast RSA algorithm*. In the paper [Modular Exponentiation using Parallel Multipliers](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.132.7490&rep=rep1&type=pdf) *modular exponentiation of long integers* is the main theme for developing fast algorithms. Maybe you also want to look at the paper about [Spectral Modular Exponentiation](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/docs/c41.pdf) with section $4.1$ talking about *Fermat/Mersenne Ring Arithmetic*.